# Read list of artists, Add top songs to playlist using Spotipy

Tags: spotify, spotipy

I am wanting to write a python program that reads a list of artists and creates a playlist with the top three songs from each artist.  Is there a way to do this directly from the artist's name or would I have to create a list of artist IDs? If that is the case - I might as well make the playlist manually.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How very timely. I literally just wrote a program that does almost exactly this today.

https://github.com/streadgold/FestivalPlaylistMaker

It reads in a list of artists (one per line) from lineup.txt and converts them to IDs and returns their top 5 tracks. Just change the limit from 5 to 3 and it sounds like it is exactly what you are asking for. Or at least a decent starting point.